# Multiple iOS Developer Accounts possible? Same company = Same DUNS

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

iOS Standard Developer accounts for companies need a DUNS for identification. What if:

1. An Enterprise Account with that DUNS already exists? When applying for a Standard Developer account with the same DUNS, the validation says that the DUNS is already in use.
2. Is it possible to have multiple Standard Developer accounts for one DUNS? In some cases 100 devices are to few for a huge company or the company does not want to mix products on the same account.

Comment: Yes, if 100 devices are less there is another developer account named as "Enterprise Account". You should take that account then..

Comment: We already have an Enterprise account. Your answer doesn't fit the question...

Comment: Then your question is wrong, for Enterprise account there is no limitation to devices..

Comment: Refer https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Comment: Just try to read it properly... I asked for Standard accounts cause Enterprise accounts have no iTunes Connect (AppStore) Distribution mechanism. We already have an Enterprise account. The question is about parallel accounts with same DUNS.

Answer (score 10):

After discussing this with Apple support:

A company can only have one standard account plus one enterprise account. Apple checks very carefully, if a company already has an account of the same type and rejects new account requests.

Comment: That's correct. I was also in contact with Apple support and got the same answer.